# Show/Hide a textbox or another dropdown or a datepicker based on value selected from a dropdown menu

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, typescript, angular2-forms

Hi i'm relatively new to angular2 development and cannot seem to find a solution to this problem:
So the UI i'm working on has a drop-down with a set of 5 options. Now on selecting any one option from the first drop-down menu i require a secondary filter for that same option inline with first dropdown to enter some field, before user can Add further filters from option1-option5.

So on selecting option-1 from dropdown menu, i would require another drop-down menu filter inline(with values a,b,c), or if selecting option-2 we should get a textbox in line to enter some data. If option-3 is entered we should provide a datepicker field for user to select date. This is the general idea.[this is how the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sIiq.png)

Please help me with what additional code i would need to type to get this above functionality running for the UI. i have attached my html code and typescript code that i have entered in VSCode below:

```
<h4>SE</h4>

<p>Filter By:</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <select 
         *ngFor="let featureSet of featureSets; let i=index" 
         class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
         type="button" id="options"
         data-toggle="dropdown" 
         (change)="OnDropdownItemSelected($event.target.value,i)">

    <span class="caret"></span>
    <option 
           *ngFor="let feature of featureSet" 
           class="dropdown-menu-item" value="{{feature}}">
      {{feature}}
    <option>
 </select>
```

below is the typescript code i have entered this far:

```
export class SE {

description = 'SE';


selections: string[];
isDisabled: boolean = true;
featureSets: any[]; //featureSets array stores data objects for all drop-downs.
items: any[];



constructor() {
    this.selections = [];
    this.featureSets = [];
    this.items = ['option-1', 'option-2', 'option-3', 'option-4', 'option-5'];
    this.addFeatures();
}


onAddClick() {

    this.addFeatures();

}

addFeatures() {
    this.featureSets.push(this.items);
    //this.featureSets.push() is adding an item set to the array each time the user clicks on the Add button.
}

public OnDropdownItemSelected(value: string, i: number) {

    //Enabling Add button upon selection.
    this.isDisabled = true;
    if (value != null && value != '') {
        this.isDisabled = false;
    }

}
```

}

Help is very much needed and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you *can* implement this:

```
public OnDropdownItemSelected(value: string) {
//Enabling Add button upon selection.
  this.isDisabled = true;
   if (value != null && value != '') {
    this.isDisabled = false;
    this.selected = value; //use selected in template
   }
}
```

Then in template:

```
<div *ngIf="selected === 'option-1'"> // here option one
</div>
<div *ngIf="selected === 'option-2'"> // here option two
</div>
```

**EDIT**

First make an array on the component scope

```
private optionsArray: any[] = [];
constructor() {
```

Then you push your selected value in this array:

```
if (value != null && value != '') {
  this.isDisabled = false;
  this.optionsArray.push({name: value}); // push value into an array
}
```

Now in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="optionsArray">
  <div *ngFor="let option of optionsArray">
    <span *ngIf="option.name === 'option-1'"> // here option one
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="option.name === 'option-2'"> // here option two
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="option.name === 'option-3'"> // here option three
    </span>
    // and more 
    // <div> will make a new row <span> stay on the same row.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying this out, but what happens is that <div *ngIf="selected === 'option-1'"> is being displayed on the screen along with a text-box that is placed inside this div even before the option-1 is selected from the dropdown. This is not the way i wanted it to function. Only after the option is selected should the text-box open inline with the dropdown.

Comment: Did you check the value of `OnDropdownItemSelected` ? It can be there goes something wrong here. Or on load you make `this.selected = '';`

Comment: the value for onDropdownItemSelected is the value of option we have chosen from the dropdown. I have made the this.selected=' '; in my typescript, but still seem to be getting the same screen as before.
this is how my screen is being shown: https://imgur.com/E2uwIJ6

Comment: @abhaydogra can you post your edited HTML? How it look now?
And double check your html it's `*ngIf=""` instead of `*ngIf""`

Comment: the edited html that ive entered now is in the image below: 
https://imgur.com/V85yjGO
also after making the changes in the html i'm now not getting the tag on my screen , but on selecting option-1. the text box that should open up inline is not appearing.
https://imgur.com/eEqEWVn

Comment: Try to check if **selected** has the value of **option-1** if it not match the *ngIf shouldn't be trigggered. You can do this with `this.selected = value; console.log(this.selected);` or show in template with `{{selected}}`.

Comment: the position of the div was a factor i think in the textbox not appearing the last time, as now on refreshing, it does give a textbox on selecting option-1.
Now upon selecting add and choosing option-2 which is again a cue to open another textbox(you can see in the code attached below), this functionality doesnt seem to be going through as only one textbox is present. but on console.log(this.selected) i get option-2
code: https://imgur.com/go7PY6D
UI screen presently: https://imgur.com/1egh4fd
console-log: https://imgur.com/eSEaEkV
now on selection of option-2 how do i show another txtbox

Comment: this is a  little beyond of the scope of the original question, but this is a necessity for the page to function correctly, help here would be greatly appreciated @swoox

Comment: @abhaydogra I see you use a second dropdown now can you show me that html code to?

Comment: the html code for the second dropdown is also written in the same html file that i have previously shared. posting an image of the complete code with both the div tags for 2 options and also it is for the dropdown functionality that i am currently using.
Any changes you'd recommend?

https://imgur.com/eBSrlOR

Comment: @abhaydogra So you want to add another textbox if you select option-2? So if you select option-1 you show a textbox and if then select option-2 you show 2 texboxes?

Comment: yes that's what needs to happen when you select option2 from 2nd dropdown(ie-show 2 textboxes), and in case if user selects option 3 in 2nd dropdown, then we need to show another dropdown for options that are sub-options of option3. that is present for 2 options(say option-3 and option-4) and in case 5th option is picked in any of the 2 dropdowns we need to display a datepicker. This is how these 2 dropdowns need to be designed

Comment: @abhaydogra This is all I can provide to give you an push in the right direction. If you want to play with multiple dropdows play with `let i = index`. Tbh it's just to much work.

Comment: so i am currently trying to create a map object with all options(ie 1-5) initially set to false, and on change of the option(when selected) i will make the corresponding value true in the map.
so in the *ngIf i will look for map['option']. if it is true then it will return the required textbox or dropdown.
This is one way im approaching it, if its not successful i will try the edit made by you and im confident it should work

Comment: // <div> will make a new row <span> stay on the same row.
^didn't exactly get what this will do.  will the textbox that opens up come inline with the dropdown, and not below it?
because that's how i would want it to appear on the screen

Comment: Plz make a new question for thatI think that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: the edit is working really fine now for a textbox, as in the textbox is opening up separately for each option. Could you help me with what i would have to add in the code to get a separate dropdown menu in case option-3 is selected. this isn't happening currently due to the code ive written. below ill give a link of the current ui-layout with the edit change and the code im implementing to make a separate dropdown appear for option-3. please suggest what changes ill need to make to get this running:
ui_layout: https://imgur.com/NpTPFWi
code for template and ts: https://imgur.com/0gcXEa0

Comment: ok will do that, please thoguh look into what ive done this far, and suggest what changes ill need to implement

Comment: `[value]="app"` for the dropdown. Instead of `appvalue={{app}}`

Comment: To set value in component use `(change)="dropdownChange()"`